# How to parse javascript DOM post data using php?

Tags: javascript, php, json, urldecode

My JavaScript sends some data to php and my php code tries to parse it but it keeps failing! The php receives the data and it is placed on text area but it is not formatted well before it get parsed. could any one tell me how to format the received data correctly so it is passable ? Thanks in advance.

javascript bookmarklet;

```
javascript: (function() {
    var d = window.open('about:blank'),
        a = d.document;
    a.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>');
    a.close();
    var b = a.body.appendChild(a.createElement('form'));
    b.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    b.setAttribute('action', 'http://mywebsite.com/test.php');
    var c = b.appendChild(a.createElement('input'));
    c.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    c.setAttribute('name', 'DOM');
    c.setAttribute('value', encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.innerHTML));
    b.submit()
})()
```

php code:

```
    $code2 = $_POST['DOM'];
    $data = json_decode($code2, true);
    print_r($data['items']);

foreach( $data['items'] as $item ) {
echo "id:".$item[ 'id' ];
echo "name:".$item[ 'name' ];
}
```

$code2 = $_POST['DOM']; data received via php looks like this :

```
 %7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22success%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22items%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22cherry%20%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22img%22%3A%20%22images%5C%2Fitems%5C%2F213433243324342cherry_fruits_logo.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item_url3%22%3A%20%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fawebsite.com%5C%2Fdo%3Fsession%3D%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22cat_id%22%3A%20%2255%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item_url2%22%3A%20%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fawebsite.com%5C%2Fdo%3Fsession%3D234123423432143242%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item_url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fawebsite.com%5C%2Fdo%3Fsession%3D23423524353454234252%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%222%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22mango%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22img%22%3A%20%22images%5C%2Fitems%5C%2F968756756mango_fruits_logo.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item_url3%22%3A%20%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fawebsite.com%5C%2Fdo%3Fsession%3D34524358098019234123%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22cat_id%22%3A%20%2255%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item_url2%22%3A%20%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fawebsite.com%5C%2Fdo%5C%2Fsession%3D34524358098019234123%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item_url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fawebsite.com%5C%2Fdo%3Fsession%3D34523454364362345134%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A
```

actual data should look like this on php:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "items": [{
                "id": "1",
                "name": "cherry ",
                "img": "images\/items\/213433243324342cherry_fruits_logo.png",
                "item_url3": "http:\/\/awebsite.com\/do?session=",
                "cat_id": "55",
                "item_url2": "http:\/\/awebsite.com\/do?session=234123423432143242",
                "item_url": "http:\/\/awebsite.com\/do?session=23423524353454234252"
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "mango",
                "img": "images\/items\/968756756mango_fruits_logo.png",
                "item_url3": "http:\/\/awebsite.com\/do?session=34524358098019234123",
                "cat_id": "55",
                "item_url2": "http:\/\/awebsite.com\/do\/session=34524358098019234123",
                "item_url": "http:\/\/awebsite.com\/do?session=34523454364362345134"
            }
```

Comment: What is you javascript code? it seems that you're seding url-endoced string and you can send just JSON.

Comment: Show your actual AJAX request (headers and body) or appropriate JS code

Comment: Thanks for replies. I edited my first post i included the bookmarklet javascript code .do you think problem is with javascript or php part ?

Comment: You shouldn't apply `encodeURIComponent` on input value cause it will be encoded autom'ly at form submission

Comment: Thanks i removed encodeURIComponent now the data recived by php is formated and i had to remove some extra html from
the data recived so it becomes valid json and i was able to parse it correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be UTF-8 encoded *as well* thus to decode it lets also use `utf8_decode()`:

```
$str = '%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22success%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22items%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22cherry%20%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22img%22%3A%20%22images%5C%2Fitems%5C%2F213433243324342cherry_fruits_logo.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item_url3%22%3A%20%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fawebsite.com%5C%2Fdo%3Fsession%3D%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22cat_id%22%3A%20%2255%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item_url2%22%3A%20%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fawebsite.com%5C%2Fdo%3Fsession%3D234123423432143242%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item_url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fawebsite.com%5C%2Fdo%3Fsession%3D23423524353454234252%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%222%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22mango%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22img%22%3A%20%22images%5C%2Fitems%5C%2F968756756mango_fruits_logo.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item_url3%22%3A%20%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fawebsite.com%5C%2Fdo%3Fsession%3D34524358098019234123%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22cat_id%22%3A%20%2255%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item_url2%22%3A%20%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fawebsite.com%5C%2Fdo%5C%2Fsession%3D34524358098019234123%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item_url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fawebsite.com%5C%2Fdo%3Fsession%3D34523454364362345134%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A';

$result = utf8_decode(urldecode($str));

print_r($result);
```